# How to make a PHP request from a static HTML in Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have 2 files `index.html` and `server.php`. The app.yaml file was configured like this to display the `index.html` page and it works fine,

```
application: orange-127906
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  static_dir: static_files

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

But I have some jQuery code inside the `index.html` file which calls the `server.php` using AJAX and displays information. Is it possible to configure the `server.php` in the `app.yaml` so that I can make those AJAX calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve a php file directly in app.yaml by using the script tag.

Example:
`-url: /
  script: server.php`

I usually serve up all of my pages with php files using the script tag and then use 'include_once' or 'require_once' to include any html files.

Comment: Awesome. That was exactly what I was struggling for. You saved my life :D

Comment: No problem. Also, you can always add html directly into any php file by writing the html outside of the php tags. Only use a static directory for, well, static files such as images, css, a jquery library, etc.